# Selenium Chrome webdriver python. How to make it work with different Existing browser profiles simultaneously?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Problem: for some reason there is a difference at working with temp profiles created by webdriver and already existing profiles.
Existing profiles directories are stored at: c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ while temp profiles folders are created at C:\Users\USERCU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7144_1693613412\Default

So. While I got my profile launched, c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1, I exec this code:

```
options = Options()

serv = Service(executable_path='resources/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                          service=serv
                          )
url = 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
```

It works perfectly fine. New Chrome instance is opened with specified url and 4s later it's closed.

However, trying to exec this code:

```
options = Options()
profile_number = 23
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument(rf'--profile-directory=Profile {profile_number}')
serv = Service(executable_path='resources/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                          service=serv
                          )
url = 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
```

result in: desired Chrome profile is launched, Chrome window is free to use, BUT no go to url.
And back to IDE there is a crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\selenium_control\test_launch_specific_profile\main2.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\selenium_control\test_launch_specific_profile\main2.py", line 76, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\crossproject_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\crossproject_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\crossproject_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\crossproject_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\crossproject_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\crossproject_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x002BF243]
    (No symbol) [0x00247FD1]
    (No symbol) [0x0013D04D]
    (No symbol) [0x0015C24E]
    (No symbol) [0x001582E9]
    (No symbol) [0x0018F056]
    (No symbol) [0x0018EB2A]
    (No symbol) [0x00188386]
    (No symbol) [0x0016163C]
    (No symbol) [0x0016269D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00559A22+2655074]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0054CA24+2601828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00368C0A+619850]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00367830+614768]
    (No symbol) [0x002505FC]
    (No symbol) [0x00255968]
    (No symbol) [0x00255A55]
    (No symbol) [0x0026051B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75C400F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CF7BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77CF7B8E+238]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

**upd**: I found out that chrome://version for any existing profile says

> Command Line   "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" **--profile-directory="Profile 1"** --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

For some reason it's always **--profile-directory="Profile 1"**.

Why so and can it be fixed?

I guess this is the problem cuz with 2 existing profiles launched in the same time webdriver can't derive which one to use and like somewhere in its implementation instead of getting single value got list of 2 instead.

Comment: Do you NEED profiles for your testing?

Comment: @MarcelWilson, yes. Check update in a post